# PC Fan working too fast even though nothing is hot

Tags: fan, desktop-computer, noise

I have a windows 10 pc with [this specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfHvK.png).

It has started to make some noise. I do not have any errors or notifications related to that. 
I used some third party programs to check fan speeds and temperature of various elements.

The results from Speedfan can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cngg3.png).

This shows that AUXTIN1 is 94C, which is pretty high. At first, I thought that was the problem which was resulting in fans rotating very fast, but the fast fan is not Aux1Fan but it is Aux3Fan, which confused me a little bit.

Hence, I am not sure if this program is any good. Therefore I tried with Speccy as well; to see the temperatures. The results from Speccy can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4vT4.png). This shows that all the temperatures are between 33-38C which sounds more realistic.

My question is: if the temperatures are all low, then why is the fan rotating very fast?

This is something I could not figure out.

The tower has a total of 6 fans in it. 
Can it be maybe one or more fans are broken? 
If that is the case, how can I test to see which one is broken?

Comment: Another prank by AUXTIN Powers... Forget those readings, they are incorrect, based on sensor returns SpeedFan simply cannot interpret correctly. If you can get a temp reading from your BIOS, it's indeed the best source of information on the subject, as the others mentioned already. This said, a fan revving at full speed all the time isn't good either, especially for your ears. Give those AUXTINx a higher temp threshold in SpeedFan, so that fan speed goes down to a more acceptable level.

Comment: That’s something good problem to have if you ask any gamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BIOS should give you the most correct temperature readings, it will also tell you what RPM the fans are spinning at etcetera, that would/could be a start, you can open the case and see if the fans are dirty, always turn off and unplug the PC before putting your hands in it, with the case open you can also visually see if the fans are spinning, obviously you need the power on for this, but keep your hands well away.

Comment: Thank you. I just did this. Apparently there are some extra sensors where two of them are showing high temperature but the CPU, GPU etc are showing good temperatures. The fans connected to those sensors are probably the ones that are rotating faster than others. Do you think the issue could be the temperature sensor, or is it the fan? Is there a way to check the wellness of temperature sensors? Thank you!.

Comment: You should take a look at the technical specifications of your PC, I am sure that a manufacturer that builds such spec should have plenty of information online, if it's custom build, you could still look at the motherboard's technical specs from its manufacturer, it will give you a better idea of what's in there and how it should run, most people don't care too much of what's in there as long as it runs when they open Facebook, but you seem to be concerned that it runs as it should, the only way you will put your mind at ease is to build the knowledge about the specific specification if it.